# USB - Simulating Storage Device

Tags: windows, usb, xbox

I have a USB 3.0 Male to Male cable and I want to have Computer A connected to Computer B through it but have Computer A recognize Computer B simply as a storage device, such as a USB drive or thumb drive.

I'd need to be able to specify which folder(s) are included on the virtual USB drive so that I can just include certain movies, music, pictures, etc. on the drive without having to relocate the files.

NOTE: This may be irrelevant but let me go into a bit more detail. Computer A is my computer while Computer B is my XBOX One. The goal is to be able to stream media through USB to my XBOX One since my WiFi is terrible and makes media buffer constantly. I am aware that I can use wired Ethernet connections since they are right next to each other but I want USB so that I can keep my LAN port on my computer open.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, this is impossible, even if you were intending to write your own device drivers: a USB host controller can't be reprogrammed to act as a device controller.

Comment: Do you have a USB device controller? Those are generally required to act as a device.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a ftp server on your PC? These use WiFi but don't need the internet they just use the router as a gateway [enter link description here][1]

http://download.cnet.com/windows/ftp-software/

Comment: You can also use bluetooth, USB Sticks etc.

Comment: I don't understand how this could possibly help my situation. As I stated earlier, I have bad WiFi and it doesn't stream smoothly...